# How to generate classes for GraphQL API (AWS AppSync) using Amplify

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-amplify-cli

I have a GraphQL API on AWS AppSync pushed by another person and want to connect to it and fetch data in my Android application. According to AWS documentation, to integrate the API with my app I should execute 3 following commands:

```
  npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
  amplify init
  amplify add codegen --apiId xxxxxx
```

After that, I need to generate Java classes based on the graphql schema. I execute `amplify codegen models` but get an error "**No AppSync API configured. Please add an API**". If execute `amplify add api`, I get "**You already have an AppSync API in your project. Use the "amplify update api" command to update your existing AppSync API.**"

Why can't I generate classes?

aws-amplify/cli v4.18.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use Amplify Mobile SDK instead of Amplify Libraries to generate classes for an API created in the AWS Console. It really confuses that you have to use different approaches for generation. In addition, on AWS in the API overview there is a wrong link which refers you not to the mobile sdk, but to the libraries.

Generation process for API created in the console is described in **Code Generation / AppSync APIs Created in the Console** https://docs.amplify.aws/sdk/api/graphql/q/platform/android#code-generation

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try running `amplify pull` to pull down the latest backend environment before running `amplify codegen models`.

Comment: `amplify pull` fails with the error: "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, stat '..\amplify\backend'"

Comment: interesting, could you show me your directory and where you're running `amplify pull` from?

Comment: I ran it from the Android Studio project root. I found out what the problem was, thanks for your help mate.